# Return single instance of multiple patterns from grep command

Tags: grep, ps

I have the output of a `ps -ef` command that returns hundreds of lines, and I need to grep for a pattern that is mostly identical, except for the number at the end, and have a single instance of each pattern returned.  Example:

this particular `ps -ef` command outputs dozens of lines, each containing the string `svc-0` or `svc-5` or any number in between 0 and 5, the `svc` numbers are randomly assigned.  If I do `grep -Eo 'svc-[0-5]'` it will just pattern-match and return each instance from every line.  I simply need to confirm the presence of `svc-0` and `svc-5`.  The output I'm hoping for is:

```
svc-0
svc-5
```

I can't just add an `-m2` to the grep, because the `svc` lines are often repeated multiple times in a row, like:

```
svc-5
svc-5
svc-5
svc-5
svc-5
svc-0
svc-0
svc-0
svc-0
svc-0
```

Comment: can you `| sort -u` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could approach it with an awk filter that looks for the two desired patterns; if both are found, then exit successfully, otherwise exit with "failure":

```
ps -ef ... | awk '/svc-0/ { zero++; } /svc-5/ { five++; } END { if (zero && five) exit 0; exit 1; }'
```